# Laravel AccessDeniedException with file download response

Tags: php, symfony, laravel-4

In my Laravel script I am writing text to a file created with `tmpfile()`, and then trying to return a file download response so the user can download that file.

```
$file = tmpfile();
fwrite($file, 'Write some text to the file.');
return Response::download(stream_get_meta_data($file)['uri'], 'myFile.txt');
```

The result is an `AccessDeniedException` saying that:

```
The file /tmp/phpJfvGtH could not be accessed
```

If I force a file download response not using Laravel's `Response` class, it works correctly:

```
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=myFile.txt');
header('Content-type: text/plain');
readfile(stream_get_meta_data($file)['uri']);
```

Why does this work, but using the `Response::download()` method does not?

I am using `Laravel Framework version 4.2.16`

Comment: Before your return statement, what does `var_export(is_readable(stream_get_meta_data($file)['uri']));` show?

Comment: It returns `true`. The exception is being thrown from the file `/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/MimeType/MimeTypeGuesser.php`, due to `is_readable($path)` returning false, which seems to contradict `var_export(is_readable(stream_get_meta_data($file)['uri']));` returning true. I'm very confused.

Comment: I assumed so. That's why I asked about is_readable. How about `$splFile = new Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File((string)stream_get_meta_data($file)['uri'])); var_export($splFile->isReadable()); var_export(is_readable($splFile->getPathname())); var_export(posix_getuid()); var_export(posix_geteuid());`

Answer (score 0):

That happens because all references to the file resource are lost. According to [tmpfile()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.tmpfile.php) documentation:

> The file is automatically removed when closed (for example, by calling fclose(), or when there are no remaining references to the file handle returned by tmpfile()), or when the script ends.

In your case your only reference to file handler `$file` is left in the current scope as you pass filepath to `download()` function, not a handler itself.

```
return Response::download(stream_get_meta_data($file)['uri'], 'myFile.txt');
```

So, what about solution:

1. You can handle file response yourself by streaming content of your tempfile i.e. `Response::stream()`
2. Or make sure somehow that reference to file handle is not lost. I made some dummy check by passing file handler to header options and it worked.
   (not sure if it breaks anything in the future, as header options are not designed for such a things)

   ```
   $file = tmpfile();
   fwrite($file, 'Write some text to the file.');
   return Response::download(stream_get_meta_data($file)['uri'], 'myFile.txt', [
       $file,
   ]);
   ```
3. Or instead of creating tempfile, create file in storage folder. And think about cleaning mechanism of your temporary files